# Save failed error in RAD

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, rad

I checked out an existing project into my work space in RAD. 
I keep on getting the following error every time I try to make any change into my existing JSP page.I was able to add a new jsp page but if I make any changes it doesn't work and gives me the same error.
 I've tried everything (Refreshing, clean build) I even re installed RAD.

Please hELP!

error:

Save Failed
Double fault during index initialization. Cause: com.ibm.etools.references.management.ReferenceException: Exception during index initialization, could not create or open index BY_SOURCELINKID-REFERENCE. Exception Cause: ReferenceExceptioncom.ibm.etools.references.management.ReferenceException: ExtentManager has detected an empty index file.  Index BY_SOURCELINKID-REFERENCE.e0 has a size of 0

Comment: "Clean" would be my first suggestion.  It sounds like your project was built on one version of RAD Developer, but you're using a different version.  For whatever it's worth, this sounds like the same problem: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=420455

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Clean Project" would be my first suggestion - but you've already tried that :(

PLAN B:

1) Exit RAD developer

2) Save a backup of your current workspace

3) *delete* `<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\com.ibm.etools.references`

4) Restart RAD developer, repeat "Project, Clean"

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have tried that as well! and it didn't work.. I get the similar error when try to open an existing jsp page. But what I right click and select open with> jsp editor it does work but still I cant save anything.

Comment: Sorry that didn't pan out :(  ANOTHER SUGGESTION: Create a brand new web project; and verify you can save *any* .jsp.  If "yes", perhaps the workaround is a) create a new project, b) manually copy your source into the project (you can do this with Windows drag/drop into the Eclipse project GUI).

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the problem. Apparently when I open a jsp page with Jsp deigner in RAD it doesn't let me save or open but if I open it with JSP editor it works fine.  not sure why..

Answer (score 0):

Had encountered a similar issue when I forcefully killed the RAD process instead of closing it. The indexation gets corrupt in some way.

I changed my workspace to point to a new location and it worked.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem.
Getting below error while saving web file(.jsp file) in RAD

[image]

Error is coming because by default your JSP page open with "**Page Editor"**

Solution is - No need to delete pulgins, just open your web file in its respective editor.
Open JSP file in **"JSP editor**".
And your proble is fixed.